# Cordova geolocation not working on android5

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using Cordova geolocation plugin. I added geolocation plugin to my app. When I run my application I just see white page. My app doesnt work. I tried emulator and on my device result is not different. Also I tried another device again result is white page. Before I looked another questions and I tried different solving way but it is not working. Please help me. I want to solve this problem.

**İt is my index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC18ssJ3hw71l5zkMYBhqBrMxqXWyCGlO8"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**İt is my index.js**

```
    var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(app.onSuccess, app.onError, app.options);  
    },
        onSuccess:function(position) {
        var lat=position.coords.latitude;
        var lng=position.coords.longitude;
        var LatLong=new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
        var mapOptions={
            center:LatLong,
            zoom:13,
            mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),mapOptions);
        var marker=new google.maps.Marker({
            position:LatLong,
            map:map,
            title:'location'
        })
    },
        onError:function (error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }   
};
app.initialize();
```

İt is my config.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.geox" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>geox</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

**İt is my res/xml/config.xml**

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.geox" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <feature name="Geolocation">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.geolocation.Geolocation" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Whitelist">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.whitelist.WhitelistPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.dialogs.Notification" />
    </feature>
    <name>geox</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
</widget>
```

Comment: what is error log?

Comment: run your appp with **cordova run android** after connect with machine then open **chrome://inspect/#devices** in chrome then inspect over there for get error logs.

Comment: I checked as you said. I get this error : Refused to load the script 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC18ssJ3hw71l5zkMYBhqBrMxqXWyCGlO8' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Comment: Also I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'querySelector' of null

Comment: did you add geolocation( **https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation**) plugin?

Comment: and add **<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * gap://ready file:; style-src http: https: 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http: https:" />** meta tag in your index.html

Comment: yes I used github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation.

Comment: what about metatag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127607/discussion-between-naitik-and-hermes).